# How to add username to graphql context/data fetching environment from RestController

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I have a spring rest controller with a single endpoint to receive all graphql query/mutation requests. the endpoint looks as below

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity testService(@RequestHeader("user") String userName, 
@RequestBody String query) {
ExecutionResult result = graphQL.execute(query);
}
```

I have properly set up my graphql object. How can I pass username from request header to graphql query so data fetcher can retrieve it to update userModified info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the simple `GraphQL#execute(String)` method, but the more powerful version `GraphQL#execute(ExecutionInput)`.

E.g.

```
ExecutionResult executionResult = graphQL.execute(ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
                .query(query)
                .context(username)
                .build());
```